# Unable to vertical scroll on menu with postion fixed and transform

Tags: css

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/rad-mej/pen/LYBverx)
I have this code: https://codepen.io/rad-mej/pen/LYBverx 
It's a mdbootstrap side menu, it has initial `transform: translateX(-100%);` and when I click to open the menu `transform: translateX(0px);`
I think position fixed and translateX causing issue with the vertical scroll. I cannot vertical scroll on that menu on mobile devices.

I tried evrything I know to make the side-nav scroll and it did not work, any help please?

Answer (score 0):

As I read your code in CodeSandbox, the reason why you cannot scroll vertically is because of the `overflow: hidden;` (line 35) in class `.side-nav`. Just replace it by `overflow: auto;`, then you can scroll normally.

The `position: fixed;` or `translateX` doesn't effect this.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I already tried that, it fix it on browser simulator, but when you tired it on the mobile it does not work.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried your original code on my phone's Chrome browser, it worked. I also tried the Chrome Devtool on my laptop, with the editted code (overflow: auto;) and it worked too. How can I reproduce your issue? :(